# Ruby: Savon AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher SOAP API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, soap, savon

I am new to SOAP and I am having lots of trouble with Savon.
The API I am trying to access has really simplistic documentation: http://www.sona-systems.com/support/docs/sona_api_docs.pdf

When making a call, the API expects authentication in the parameters being sent. Here is my code:

```
client = Savon.client(
wsdl: "https://school.sona-systems.com/services/SonaAPI.svc?singleWsdl",
soap_header: {'To:' => "http://www.sona-systems.com/"},
pretty_print_xml: true,
soap_version: 2
)

response = client.call(:get_study_list) do
  message username: "foo", password: "bar"
end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Savon::SOAPFault: (s:Sender) The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the `soap_header:` suppose to do?

I also cannot get to the url you provided. you should add `log: true, log_level: :debug` to your client definition to get more information.

try this:

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "https://kellogg-elab.sona-systems.com/services/SonaAPI.svc?wsdl",
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  log: true,
  log_level: :debug
)
puts client.operations

# then call a method of the service like this

resp = client.call(:get_study_list,
               message: {username: "foo", password: "bar"}
              )
```

Comment: Steffen, thanks for your response.
The header was supposed to fix the empty To that Savon is giving me, not sure if that works at all...

I can read the operations, but when calling on the different methods I get the error above. The correct link would be https://kellogg-elab.sona-systems.com/services/SonaAPI.svc?singleWsdl"

Comment: I added an example for a call. You don't give it a block, but parameters. The message is obviously not a fit for the specific call but you should get the idea what do put in there.